# How do I get rid of orphaned application entries after uninstallation?

Tags: macos, applications, calendar, ical, defaults

Orphaned Entry in Default Calendar App Preferences (OS X Yosemite)?

The image below is the preferences pane in Calendar.app. This is where the user sets the default calendar app used by OS X globally. In OS X 10 this is set to Calendar.app by default. I use Fantastical 2 as my default calendar app. The problem is an orphaned entry is appearing -specifically MobileCal.app- (as can be seen in the image below). As far as I can recall I've never installed an app called MobileCal. Please let me know i) how to remove this orphaned entry and ii) how it got there in the first place. I'm running OS X Yosemite 10.0.3. Thanks! [image: preferences pane in Calendar.app]Additionally I'm receiving the following error when I attempt to open a reminder from Spotlight Search:[image]

Comment: Remove it from your Applications folder and it should disappear from that list.

Comment: MobileCal.app does not exist in my applications folder.

Comment: I would start by installing Onyx for Yosemite (hopefully you meant 10.10.3) from titanium.free.fr, then using the Automation section to do maintenance, but particularly to rebuild the Launchservices database and remove caches for both user and system.

Comment: @Trellis Just rebuilding launchservices is not going to do it. MobileCal.app clearly exists somewhere on the OP's system, or it would not get so far as to tell him that the app is for a different type of Mac (I'm guessing it's referring to a PowerPC app).

Comment: @MikeWidman What happens if you search for MobileCal.app in Spotlight? Or in Terminal by using `mdfind -name MobileCal` or `locate MobileCal`?

Comment: @Trellis Searching in spotlight reveals nothing. Using The "mdfind -name MobileCal" reveals nothing and the "locate MobileCal" command comes back with "WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist."

Comment: Weird thing: I never (knowingly) installed an application called MobileCal.app and I can't find any information about this application on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MobileCal.app is part of Xcode's iPhone SDK, so the easiest way to get rid of that app is to either remove the Xcode completely or remove just the app. The file can be located inside the Xcode package:

`Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications`